# VS 2013 error with online TFS Service "The decryption operation failed, see inner exception"

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

While adding many 1000s of files to the online version of TFS at visualstudio.com, I have started getting `"The decryption operation failed, see inner exception"`.

I cannot even resolve or check in a single file (from the new batch of 34,000+ additions).

As the message is displayed in the pending changes window, there is no way *that I can see* to get more details (or view the inner exception).

1) Is this a TFS, VS 2013 or network issue
2) How can I get at the more detail information of the error in VS 2013?

- Before anyone suggests *"turn it off and on again"*, rebooting has not made any difference to the problem.
- Also switching the advanced workspace location from "local" to "server" made no difference.

Have we just hit a wall in TFS?

*Note: It does not effect checkin to other folders outside of the new additions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the online TFS service provided through visualstudio.com has some limitations.

The solution to the problem above was to undo the 34,000+ item check and **add them in smaller batches**. Up to around 10,000 files at a time seems to behave itself.

### Update:

I have just had the same error on a fresh machine install, where I tried to pull down my entire TFS repository in one go. Again pulling them down piece-by-piece avoided the error